# Go idiomatic way to name boolean predicate functions

Tags: go

Lets say you are working with a func that returns a bool as to whether a user has been active in the last month.

In Ruby:

```
def active_in_last_month?;end
```

In C#

```
public bool WasActiveInLastMonth(){}
```

What is the idiomatic way of naming boolean predicate functions in Go?

Comment: I saw people debate this in this github issue, maybe it helps you to understand golang convention.

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26111

Answer (score 14):

**tl;dr**

```
func wasActiveInLastMonth() bool
```

**Full Answer**

I looked in the GitHub repos of some well known open source projects, picked a semi-random file, and found the following:

Etcd lease/lessor.go

```
func (le *lessor) isPrimary() bool
```

Kubernetes service/service_controller.go

```
func (s *ServiceController) needsUpdate(oldService *v1.Service, newService *v1.Service) bool

func portsEqualForLB(x, y *v1.Service) bool

func portSlicesEqualForLB(x, y []*v1.ServicePort) bool
```

Consul agent/acl.go

```
func (m *aclManager) isDisabled() bool
```

Docker Moby (open source upstream of Docker) cli/cobra.go

```
func hasSubCommands(cmd *cobra.Command) bool

func hasManagementSubCommands(cmd *cobra.Command) bool
```

I would say that these four projects represent some of the most well reviewed and famous go code in existence. It seems that the is/has pattern is very prevalent although not the only pattern. If you choose this pattern you will certainly be able to defend your choice as a de facto idiom.

Comment: The go source code itself uses `is`: https://golang.org/src/go/types/predicates.go

Comment: What to do in case if a predicate function can return error? declare as `func isPrimary() (bool, error)`? Is it common approach?

Comment: That is what I would do.

Answer (score -2):

"The Go Programming Language" by Donovan and Kernighan recommends in Chapter 6 that

> Functions that merely access or modify internal values of a type..are called getters and setters.  However, when naming a getter method we usually omit the Get prefix.  This Preference for brevity extends to all methods not just field accessors, and to other reductant prefixes as well, such as Fetch, Find and Lookup

From this advice I would name the function "LastMonth"  Or "lastMonth" if it is private to the package to skip the prefix

Comment: This answer is being downvoted not because it's bad advice, but because it doesn't pertain to the question being asked. OP specifically asked about naming for a function that returns bool, not for a Getter or Setter which is the only thing being addressed by your answer.

Comment: That’s because their answer was more well thought out and relevant to the OP. Not just randomly quoting a book and taking stuff out of context.